# python decorators running all at once

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

i am new to decorators and i am using python 2.7 due to some legacy code

decorator

```
def print_sep_args(param, color):
    print_separator(length=128)
    print_color('=' * 60 + 'Checking for {0}'.format(param) + '=' * 60, color)
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Functions calling decorator

```
@print_sep_args('Session Related Info', 'red')
def check_sessionaccount():
    print('test')

@print_sep_args('Session Related Info', 'blue')
def check_hire_date():
    print('test2')
```

Output:

```
============================================================Checking for Session Related Info============================================================    ============================================================Checking for Session Related Info============================================================
test
test2
```

Expected Output:

```
============================================================Checking for Session Related Info============================================================
test
============================================================Checking for Session Related Info============================================================
test2
```

In other words, both decorators are running before the code is run.

```
def main():
    check_sessionaccount()
    check_hiredate()
```

Comment: move prints into `decorator(func)`. Right now prints are executed before any method is called

Comment: The outer part of the decorator runs at the time the function is defined; you need to move the `print` into the inner part

Comment: It works now! thank you so much. would love to accept it as an answer but its a comment